# Huge packet loss while performing l2 forwarding using packet gen

Tags: virtual-machine, packet-loss, huge-pages

Am facing severe packet loss while performing Packet forwarding using Packet gen DPDK. Any packets equal to 500 and above that results in huge packet loss. I have learnt about DPDK architecutre from its main site. I have changed MBUF values and also cahce size, but still no luck. Any help would be much apprecitated. I am uploading every single image to get an idea on what I am doing.

[image: DPDK to perform L2 Forwarding VM Settings]

[image: Packet Gen DPDK VM Settings]

Packet Gen DPDK VM Settings

[image: Packet Gen DPDK HugePages]

[image: Packet Gen DPDK HugePages Non NUMA]

[image: PACKET GEN DPDK TOOLS RUN.PY]

[image: BINDED DEVICES PACKET GEN DPDK]

[image: PACKET GEN DPDK PACKET SETTING]

[image: PACKET GEN DPDK PACKET FLOW]

L2FWD VM

[image: DPDK HUGEPAGES NUMA]

[image: DPDK HUGEPAGES NON NUMA]

[image: DPDK L2Fwd VM Binded Devices]

[image: L2FWD Running]

[image: l2 Forwarding]

Comment: There many factors affecting performance. As O recollect we had walked through the same in 'stackoverflow and Skype'. For better understanding share details of system, vcpu pinning, huge page backing, please use kvm qux or xen than virtual box. If you still want to use virual box use pcie pass through rather than tap port for vitio

Comment: Welcome on the SO! 1. It is not a programming a question, I think you should visit https://unix.stackexchange.com 2. Please do not include screenshots if you can copy-paste text, too.

Comment: @Saifullah are there any updates with regard to the missing information?

Comment: @SaifUllah I am waiting for updates, hence marking the ticket requires as more details.

Comment: @VipinVarghese am searching for the terms you listed above.  I have not heard about them before. Once I understand then I will discuss it further.

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica So Am I not allowed to post network related query here?

Comment: @SaifUllah Yes, you can.

Comment: @SaifUllah the issue is not in DPDK but your environment. Please edit and modify with the right information.

Comment: @SaifUllah https://stackoverflow.com is for entirely programming questions. https://unix.stackexchange.com or https://askubuntu.com is for unix/linux/ubuntu questions. https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com is for (professional) network management questions.